# Effect of Order By in sub-query on outer query sorting

Tags: mysql

I have a query with sub-query getting data from other tables. Does the order by clause in sub-query also sorts the records of the outer query in the same order??

Query is of the form:

```
select p.email email, max(p.firstname) firstname,max(p.lastname) lastname  
from abc p, xyz c 
where p.companyid=c.companyid 
and  c.company!=''  
and locationid in (  
                   select locationid  
                   from mno tr   
                   where 1=1 
                   AND tr.inc in (7,8,9)  
                   AND tr.topic in( 'Callidus Cloud')  
                   AND tr.inc IS NOT NULL  
                   order by inc desc 
                  ) 
AND c.crange IN ('100-249','250-499','500-999','1000-4999'
                  ,'5000-9999','50000-100000','>100000') 
group by p.email limit 7 offset 0
```

Comment: No, why do you think it would?

Comment: Best change the implicit join to and explicit join

Comment: No, it doesn't sort the outer query. You should remove it (you don't need it there) and, if you want the result ordered, put a new order by in th outer join

Comment: One possible effect is when you do other things inside the subquery. For instance, inserting `top 10` in the inner query will (probably) return a different subset whether you order or not. But it does not affect the sort order of the result.

Comment: I don't have that column 'inc' in outer query tables and joining is a big no as the data is hugh. So, if IN clause works such that for outer query also, results come in the same order, that i wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

What happens in sub query remains in sub query. It only returns the value you asked for.